# How to get the Content-Length header from a POST request send with axios?

Tags: javascript, http-headers, axios, httprequest, interceptor

I want to use the size and data of my POST request. I was doing some research and found out about the Content-Length header of a request, but I can't find it in my axios request headers.

I tried using interceptors, like that :

```
axios.interceptors.request.use(
    config => {
        console.log('config', config.headers);
        if (config.url != `${API_URL}/login`)
            config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + getAccessToken();
        return config;
    },

    error => {
        return Promise.reject(error);
    }
);
```

And here is the response that I get:

```
Authorization: "Bearer [...access_token]"
Content-Type: "multipart/form-data"
common:
    Accept: "application/json, text/plain, */*"
    X-CSRF-TOKEN: "..."
    X-Requested-With: "XMLHttpRequest"
    __proto__: Object
delete: {}
get: {}
head: {}
patch: {Content-Type: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}
post: {Content-Type: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}
put: {Content-Type: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}
```

But in in Chrome this is what is shown:

```
Accept: application/json, text/plain
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,ro;q=0.8,la;q=0.7
Authorization: Bearer [...access_token]
Connection: keep-alive

Content-Length: 5266672 <---- this is what I need

Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryGMzak87LIZH05nme
Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN= ...
Host: ...
Origin: ...
Referer: ...
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.90 Safari/537.36
X-CSRF-TOKEN: ...
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
X-XSRF-TOKEN: ...
```

Is there any way to make axios give me the content-length header? If not, is there any way to access it from anywhere else?

Answer (score 0):

content-length will auto add by [http adapter](https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/master/lib/adapters/http.js#L45).

Comment: Can we read this value in request interceptor?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to get the auto-calculated `Content-Length` header value, but I think you could calculate it manually like this:

```
axios.interceptors.request.use(
  config => {
    if (config.method === 'post') {
      let contentLength = Array.from(config.data.entries(), ([_, prop]) =>
        ({
          size: typeof prop === 'string' ? prop.length : prop.size
        })).reduce((currentValue, nextItem) => {
        return currentValue + nextItem.size;
      }, 0);

      console.log("Content-Length header expected value: ", contentLength)
      return config;
    }
  },

  error => {
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);
```